# GORM setup using Gradle and Groovy

Tags: groovy, grails-orm

Can anyone please share the steps to setup GORM using gradle and use the same in groovy ?

Answer (score 1):

GORM for Hibernate has [excellent documentation](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/#springBoot)

Particularly the section of [Using GORM For Hibernate Outside Grails](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/#outsideGrails)

At minimum you need:

```
compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5:6.1.10.RELEASE"
runtime "com.h2database:h2:1.4.192"
runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.0"
runtime "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:8.5.0"
runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10"
```

Entities should go under `src/main/groovy`

```
@Entity
class Person implements GormEntity<Person> { 
    String firstName
    String lastName
    static constraints = {
        firstName blank:false
        lastName blank:false
    }
}
```

and then finally bootstrap the data store somewhere:

```
import org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore

Map configuration = [
    'hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto':'create-drop',
    'dataSource.url':'jdbc:h2:mem:myDB'
]
HibernateDatastore datastore = new HibernateDatastore( configuration, Person)
```

Comment: i had to use `org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5:6.1.10.RELEASE` since `org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5:6.1.10.RELEASE` depends on `org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:6.1.10.RELEASE` that does not exists right now https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core (grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core)